# MySQL: selecting joined rows, where children don't belong to a specific parents id

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, right-join

The question might sound a little confusing, I'll do my best to explain it. I have 4 tables:

- **store_item**: products
- **store_cat**: product categories. Each product has 1 category.
- **store_cat_attribute**: category attributes. Each category has N attributes.
- **store_item_stock**: product stock by attribute

The objective is to get **all** the `id`s from the `store_item_stock` table for a specific product, as long as the `store_item_stock.id_attribute` is **not** linked to the current `store_item.id_cat`

Here's the SQLfiddle for the structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d686b9/2

My current query actually gets all the `store_item_stock` rows for a product, but it is also including the attributes that belong to the current `store_item.id_cat`:

```
SELECT store_item_stock.id, store_item_stock.id_attribute, store_item_stock.stock
FROM store_item_stock
LEFT JOIN store_item ON store_item.id_item = store_item_stock.id_item
LEFT JOIN store_cat_attribute ON store_cat_attribute.id_cat = store_item.id_cat
WHERE store_item_stock.id_item = 1 AND store_item.id_cat = 2 GROUP BY store_item_stock.id
```

For example, `id_attribute` 2, 3 & 4 belong to `id_cat` 2, and `id_attribute` 33 & 34 belong to `id_cat` 4, so if the query's purpose were to get ALL the `store_item_stock` rows except for those that have their `id_attribute` linked to `store_item.id_cat` 2, it should return:

- **id**: 104, **id_attribute**: 33, **stock**: 26
- **id**: 105, **id_attribute**: 34, **stock**: 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT store_item_stock.id, store_item_stock.id_attribute, store_item_stock.stock 
FROM store_item_stock 
JOIN store_cat_attribute 
ON store_item_stock.id_attribute=store_cat_attribute.id_attribute
WHERE id_cat NOT IN (
SELECT store_item.id_cat 
FROM store_item JOIN store_cat_attribute 
ON store_item.id_cat=store_cat_attribute.id_cat 
WHERE store_item.id_cat=2 
GROUP BY store_item.id_cat);
```

I wouldn't think that it's this simple but let's try this one out and see if the condition matches your desired output.

Comment: Hi, I did end with this working query: `SELECT * FROM store_item_stock WHERE id_item = :id_item AND id_attribute NOT IN(SELECT store_cat_attribute.id_attribute FROM store_cat_attribute JOIN store_item ON store_item.id_cat = store_cat_attribute.id_cat WHERE store_item.id_item = :id_item GROUP BY store_item.id_cat)`

Comment: Great! @AndresSK